# External DLL in VB6 with namespaces

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, dllimport

I'm currently having some trouble with a VB6 application that needs to encode some text using the same encoding method available at .NET framework 4.5.
I've searched through the internet and found some functions that tries to do the encoding based in UTF-8, but it still doesn't match the 4.5 output.

Then I looked for a way to import the 4.5 framework DLL within the VB6 project. This is what I accomplished so far:

```
Private Declare Function dotNetUrlEncode Lib "System.Web.dll" Alias "UrlEncode" (str As String) As String
```

The problem is that the method "UrlEncode" it's inside the namespace "HttpUtility", "System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode" and using the code above I cant access the method. I've tried changing it to look like the code below, but the problem persists, I cant reach the method UrlEncode:

```
Private Declare Function dotNetUrlEncode Lib "System.Web.dll" Alias "HttpUtility.UrlEncode" (str As String) As String
Private Declare Function dotNetUrlEncode Lib "System.Web.HttpUtility.dll" Alias "UrlEncode" (str As String) As String
```

Is there a way to reach the method UrlEncode inside "System.Web.dll"? Where am I going wrong?

Thanks for the help!

Best regards.

Comment: you might want to look into the COM Callable Wrapper. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look!

Comment: Bringing in .net is a crazy approach. You really should find a solution without .net. Don't give up so easily!

Comment: Isn't that an ASP.Net-only namespace anyway?  MSDN: "To encode or decode values outside of a web application, use the WebUtility class."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not work. The .NET DLLs contained *managed* code, which requires the .NET runtime. Your VB6 app can't call that code. Its process does not have the .NET runtime loaded.

You can only import functions from *native* DLLs this way. That's why it works for system DLLs included with the operating system.

The best solution would really be to consult the documentation and determine precisely how the `UrlEncode` function works. The internals of the implementation will not be documented, of course, but that doesn't matter. All you're interested in is the specification. Follow that same specification when implementing your own function if you cannot find a system function that has equivalent behavior.

If you absolutely needed to call .NET functions from a VB 6 application, it can be done. You will need to create a .NET wrapper that calls the framework-provided function and exposes in a COM-compatible manner using the `ComVisibleAttribute`. More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973802.aspx), [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/817248), and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx).

Comment: First of all, thanks for your attention! I'll take a look at the documentation, but I have one more question: And if I create a new dll using .NET and inside this DLL a new method that simply returns the 4.5 framework output of UrlEncode? Will I be able to use the way I mentioned above?

Comment: Assuming you take the steps required to make the .NET assembly visible from a COM application (the VB 6 one).

Comment: No true. You can use, for instance, Robert Giesecke's UnmanagedExports. Or you can wrap it in a C++/CLI mixed mode assembly. The former is by far the simplest. However, bringing .net into the process is a simply crazy idea!

Comment: @David Interesting, I'd never heard of Unmanaged Exports. I'm curious how it works. Any idea where I can find out? The web page is very sparse on details, and it doesn't appear to be open source. I'm assuming it modifies the IL, but what modifications does it make to overcome the problem of .NET assemblies requiring the .NET runtime?

Comment: The .net runtime is still loaded. The IL is modified. In the same way as a mixed mode C++/CLI module can export unmanaged functions.